Notation about a point and a plane
Suppose I want to show that the point $P=(1,-2,0)$ is on the plane $\Pi:2x-y+z=4$. What would be a good notation for,

$\text{suitable-notation}=4$

I ask because I do not want to confuse people with something that may be already widely used for something else. I thought something like $\Pi[P]=4$, or maybe, $\Pi[1,-2,0]=4$. Is there a somewhat accepted notation for cases like this?

Saying that a point is on a plane, and equating that inclusion to a value of 4, are two different things. Why the "=4" at all?

$f(x,y,z) = 2x - y + z \implies f(1,-2,0) = 4.$

$P \in \Pi$? (the formula of $\Pi$ is not $2x-y+z=4$ but $2x-y+z-4=0$)

If you have the dot-product available, then $n. P = 4$ where $n = (2,-1,1)$ is a normal vector for $\Pi$.

There is a lot of confusion. First of all, let's start by remembering that
"$\Pi:2x-y+z=4$" is an abreviation to say that $$\Pi=\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3:2x-y+z=4\}$$or $$M=(x,y,z)\in \Pi \iff 2x-y+z=4$$
Here $$2\times \color{red}1-\color{green}{(-2)}+\color{blue}0=4.$$
Hence $P=(\color{red}1,\color{green}{-2},\color{blue}0)\in \Pi$. Otherwise said, $P$ is on the plane $\Pi$.
However, behind these confusions hide some interesting notions. Indeed if we introduce $$f:\mathbb R^3\to \mathbb R$$ $$M=(x,y,z)\mapsto 2x-y+z$$we have $$\Pi=\{M\in \mathbb R^3:f(M)=4\}$$
